# enumerate array and report contiguous occurrences with index range

Tags: php, arrays, report, indexing, frequency

what sort of php array enumeration must I use to get from this array:

`[0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 42 [5] => 42 [6] => 42 [7] => 42 [8] => 36 [9] => 36 [10] => 0 [11] => 36 [12] => 36 [13] => 36 [14] => 36 [15] => 36 [16] => 42 [17] => 42 [18] => 42 [19] => 42 [20] => 42 [21] => 42 [22] => 42 [23] => 0`

to this report:

```
index 0 to index 4   ... 0
index 4 to index 8   ... 42
index 8 to index 16  ... 36
index 16 to index 23 ... 42
index 23             ... 0
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: for($x<0;$x<24;$x++) ... but what do afterwards? ... that's my headache.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question. Are the index ranges hard coded or dynamic in some way? Is the length of the array variable or will it always be 24 elements long?

Comment: always 24 elements; always index enumerated 0 -> 23 value sequences can change; n.b. [15] should be 36, not *36 (typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$startIndex = 0;
$endIndex = 0;
$lastVal = $arr[0];

for($i=1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
   if ($arr[$i] == $lastVal) {
       $endIndex = $i;
   } else {
       echo "index $startIndex to $endIndex ... $lastVal";
       $startIndex = $i + 1;
       $endIndex = $i + 1;
       $lastVal = $arr[$i + 1]
   }
}
```

I know there are some issues when you get to the end of the array and if the index range is only 1 long but this is the general idea and definitely should be enough to get you going

Comment: cursory glance indicates viability; will walk it into the lab, hook up electrodes and see if it comes to life; many thanks for your prompt and to-the-point response.

Comment: works flawlessly. once again, thanks for taking the time to sort this out.

Comment: @amalafrida That's what those upvote and accept buttons are for :)

Comment: new to this site, but man is it cool! what a fine resource. was wondering ... made some adjustments to your solution in order to take care of the 1-element case and the end-of-array anomaly. Should I post those modifications here?